# How to bundle sounds with Codename One?

Tags: audio, codenameone

I want to include sounds in my Codename One app for effects like clicking a button, transitions, etc. I prefer not to download them from URL, since they are very small and I want them to be played even when the device is not connected to the internet. It looks like I cannot include the source files in the theme. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the sound file in the "src" folder inside your project folder and reference it like below:

```
private Media MEDIA = null;
public void playAudio(String fileName) {
    try {
        if (MEDIA == null) {
            final InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + fileName);
            MEDIA = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/mp3", new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MEDIA = null;
                }
            });
        }
        if (MEDIA != null && MEDIA.isPlaying() == false) {
            MEDIA.setVolume(100);
            MEDIA.play();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}

...

playAudio("my_sound.mp3");
```