# Playing Background Music From Bundled File in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to have a background sound play in codenameone from an mp3 file that's packaged with the app (beep-07.mp3 is just in the src folder).

I can make it work using MediaManager.createMedia, with code borrowed from this post: [How to bundle sounds with Codename One?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029586/how-to-bundle-sounds-with-codename-one)

But the MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia function only takes in a uri, so I try using MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia("file://beep-07.mp3"); but no sound plays.

Am I doing something wrong in the file string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src directory doesn't exist on the device. The files that are there are packaged as resources into the equivalent of a jar. So you need to extract them if you want a URL. Notice this might work with `"jar://beep-07.mp3"` but I'm not sure.

A more correct approach would be to extract it from the jar on first use then use this URL (the code below assumes static import of the `CN` class):

```
String fileName = getAppHomePath() + "beep-07.mp3";
if(!existsInFileSystem(fileName)) {
    try(InputStream i = getResourceAsStream("/beep-07.mp3");
       OutputStream o = openFileOutputStream(fileName)) {
        copy(i, o);
    }
}
Media m = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia(fileName);
```

FYI since your app is running you don't need background media only foreground media.

Comment: Both methods you've suggested work! And just to note, I'm using background media so that my sounds don't stop music playing from another app (the beep is just a notification for a timer - and depending on the user they may have minimized the app while the timer is running).